# Does exist orWhere method in laravel-translatable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use [this](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) library Laravel for translations

Does exist `orwhereTranslationLike` method in laravel-translatable?

When I use two methods it work logiclty as AND conditions:

```
$query->whereTranslationLike('title', '%' . $term . '%');
$query->whereTranslationLike('decs', '%' . $term . '%');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$query->where(function($q) use($term) {
    $q->whereTranslationLike('title', '%' . $term . '%');
})->orWhere(function($q) use($term) {
    $q->whereTranslationLike('decs', '%' . $term . '%');
});
```